# How can I create a new directory, copy the folders and rename it with Powershell?

Tags: regex, powershell, directory

I have a directory(A) with folders named "F-1234 blablabla", "F-2345 blublublu" and so on.

Yet I want write a script in Powershell who creates a new directory(B) and that copy the folders and rename the folders to "F-1234", "F-2345 and so on.

How can I do that?

My code so far, I have made a "simulation" of the folder:

```
$folder = "F-1234 blablabla", "F-1020 blablabl"
$found = $folder -replace "(^F\-((?:[0-9]){4}))"

If($found = 'True'){
Write-Output $result = $1
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Im sure you will find everything you need on so.

Comment: I have tried to rename with `$found = $folder -replace "(^F\-((?:[0-9]){4}))"`.

Comment: $folder is a variable, not a reference to the folder in your filesystem. Kind of like if you jot a note down from a blackboard, modifying your note won't affect the source. Look into the `Rename-Item` command.